# Running Count by Group and Flag in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that looks like the below:

```
Row | Fullvisitorid | Visitid | New_Session_Flag 
1   | A             | 111     | 1
2   | A             | 120     | 0
3   | A             | 128     | 0
4   | A             | 133     | 0
5   | A             | 745     | 1
6   | A             | 777     | 0
7   | B             | 388     | 1
8   | B             | 401     | 0
9   | B             | 420     | 0
10  | B             | 777     | 1
11  | B             | 784     | 0
12  | B             | 791     | 0
13  | B             | 900     | 1  
14  | B             | 904     | 0
```

What I want to do is if it's the first row for a fullvisitorid then mark the field as 1, otherwise use the above row as the value, but if the new_session_flag = 1 then use the above row plus 1, example of output I'm looking for below:

```
Row | Fullvisitorid | Visitid | New_Session_Flag | Rank_Session_Order
1   | A             | 111     | 1                | 1
2   | A             | 120     | 0                | 1
3   | A             | 128     | 0                | 1
4   | A             | 133     | 0                | 1
5   | A             | 745     | 1                | 2
6   | A             | 777     | 0                | 2
7   | B             | 388     | 1                | 1
8   | B             | 401     | 0                | 1
9   | B             | 420     | 0                | 1
10  | B             | 777     | 1                | 2
11  | B             | 784     | 0                | 2
12  | B             | 791     | 0                | 2
13  | B             | 900     | 1                | 3
14  | B             | 904     | 0                | 3
```

As you can see:

- Row 1 is 1 because it's the first time fullvisitorid A appears
- Row 2 is 1 because it's not the first time fullvisitorid A appears and new_session_flag <> 1 therefore it uses the above row (i.e. 1)
- Row 5 is 2 because it's not the first time fullvisitorid A appears and new_session_Flag = 1 therefore it uses the above row (i.e 1) plus 1
- Row 7 is 1 because it's the first time fullvisitorid B appears

  etc.

I believe this can be done through a `retain` statement in SAS but is there an equivalent in Google BigQquery?

Hopefully the above makes sense, let me know if not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: (1) There is no `retains`.  (2) There are very powerful constructs that are not available in proc SQL.  (3) Your question is too difficult to follow.  If you show the data as a *text* table with just the handful of columns you need and then explain what *results* you want to see, then it would be much simpler to answer.

Comment: No. There is no such function. And I second @GordonLinoff - difficult to follow if even possible at all. I suggest you to reshape your question and focus on what you want to accomplish and presenting sample input data as well as expected output in text - not as images! Without doing this  - right now your chances to get answer is close to zero. Not a zero though :o)

Comment: There are full SQL solutions to this, I don't know BigQuery well enough to comment but search for 30 day readmission problem which is essentially what this is, except you're using a much smaller interval.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant, thanks for the feedback, I though the screenshots might make things more obvious but obviously not.  I've tried to simplify my explanation, can you let me know if this is in a more useful format?

Comment: absolutely! thank you for following suggestion. see the answer :o)

Comment: I took liberties in removing sas in tags and title as this statistical package is not directly relevant here just a tangential reference. Also, future readers for BigQuery solutions may not know anything about SAS.

Answer (score 3):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *,
  COUNTIF(New_Session_Flag = 1) OVER(PARTITION BY Fullvisitorid  ORDER BY Visitid) Rank_Session_Order
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Mikhail Berlyant using a conditional window count is corret and works. I am answering because I find that a window sum is even simpler (and possibly more efficient on a large dataset):

```
select
    t.*,
    sum(new_session_flag) over(partition by fullvisitorid order by visid_id) rank_session_order
from mytable t
```

This works because the `new_session_flag` contains `0`s and `1`s only; so counting the `1`s is actually equivalent to suming all values.